# Android saving dilemma' was using serialization, which is wrong

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a class, Savable that serialize the entire class. It was quick easy and great. Unfortunately, this is a problem if I want to update my app. If I make *any* changes to Saveable, or its descendants, when an instance is deserialized from an older version, there are virtual, and or abstract errors and other errors thrown.

Reading the Android saving data page [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html), developers are supposed to use one of the ways listed. As I am building an alarm app, I have opted for the SQLLite option.

The problem, until now, my app has been created with my Saveable class in mind. Switching to a database will require a full reworking of my Alarm class because Alarm has other descendants of Saveable in it. Therefore, to save each alarm, I will need a database for every sub-class of Saveable.

Currently, I have a method, Saveable.save(Context context) that serializes the object to fill. This will require a rewrite because now instead of serializing the entire Alarm class, I need to save the core Alarm stuff the Alarm.db, the subclasses of Saveable into subclass.db.

This presents another issue now with loading. I have a method, Saveable.LOAD(File path), which deserializes a Saveable object, that can be cast to it's original class. Now, since the Alarm class contains other Saveable objects that need to be saved in separate DBs, the Alarm class will need a reference to the each sub-saveable class in alarm.

Needless to say, this becomes explosively messy, quickly. I am not opposed to the work (programming is amazing), but before I short change myself again, is this the way you would solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest you back off of your entire approach.  What are you actually trying to do?  Serializing your class is a solution, what's the problem?  Because serializing your class in *any* format will have problems like this, which is why its generally not a great idea.  It seems like a nice quick way to save, but it almost always ends up biting you in the end.

Comment: @GabeSechan I am trying to update my class to a proper way of saving, so that every time I update, I do not have to erase the person's save data and/or risk crashing because I modified a Serializable class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newer programmer, but can't you get a serialization code for updating that allows an object/class to used with an updated version by going into the command line and putting say: serialver class name and it spits out the static final longserialVersionUID.  Then make a static final long serialVersionUID = (insert random long number the command line gives here) in the class you want to serialize and then use with an updated version of the program.  You probably already know this, and may not be the answer you are looking for, but me being new its the only way I have heard of serializing a class, updating the source code, then deserializing a class and using it with the updated code.